# Jsonb array of objects update

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

So this is my jsonb array of objects. Column is called bids in my db.

[bids column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICLSB.png)

```
 [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "size": "5.5Y",
        "price": 180
      },
      {
        "id": "f0d1d36a-f6af-409e-968e-54c1dc104566",
        "size": "6.5Y",
        "price": 22
      }
    ]
```

**I want to update price property by the ID of an element for ex. "f0d1d36a-f6af-409e-968e-54c1dc104566", so the price would change from 22 to 150 IN ROW WHICH CONTAINS ELEMENT WITH DESIRED ID IN THE COLUMN.
How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table json_update (id integer, json_fld jsonb);
insert into json_update values (1, '[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "size": "5.5Y",
        "price": 180
      },
      {
        "id": "f0d1d36a-f6af-409e-968e-54c1dc104566",
        "size": "6.5Y",
        "price": 22
      }
    ]'
)
;


UPDATE
    json_update
SET
    json_fld = jsonb_set(json_fld, ARRAY[(idx)::text, 'price'::text], '150'::jsonb)
FROM (
    SELECT
        (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.a ->> 'id') - 1) AS idx,
        t.a
    FROM (
        SELECT
            jsonb_array_elements(json_fld)
        FROM
            json_update) AS t (a)) AS i
WHERE
    i.a ->> 'id' = 'f0d1d36a-f6af-409e-968e-54c1dc104566';

select * from json_update ;
 id |                                                         json_fld                                                          
----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"id": "1", "size": "5.5Y", "price": 180}, {"id": "f0d1d36a-f6af-409e-968e-54c1dc104566", "size": "6.5Y", "price": 150}]
```

Comment: Thank you! Can i somehow maintain the id 1 record without deleting it? So it would keep the rest of array as it was

Comment: Oops, that is not good. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: See corrected answer.

Comment: Does It work for you also if you add a few more rows? I tried executing it without adding another condition in the last WHERE and also with adding another condition but either of times it didnt update the row for me.

Comment: More rows(objects) in the `json` or in the table? Add to your question what you attempted and what failed.

Comment: I added picture for reference for you, wanted to change only the object in desired row I bumped into something like this: 
update tbl
set col = new_col_value
from (select id as ref_id, ... as new_col_value from tbl) as tbl_new
where tbl_new.ref_id = tbl.id. Thank you in advance

Comment: **Do not** use images copy and paste as text into the question.